# Upload images from local machine to amazon S3 using Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I want to upload image files in amazon s3 using django and django rest-framework. Following are the code snippets from my project.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image_meta = models.ForeignKey('Image_Meta',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images-data')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        field = ('id', 'image_path' , 'order' , 'version')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns , include , url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from imagedata import  views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^image/$',views.ImageList.as_view(),name='image_list'),
    url(r'^image/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ImageDetail.as_view(),name='image_detail'),
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'Component': reverse('component_list', request=request),
        'Image Type': reverse('imagetype_list', request=request),
        'Image Component':reverse('imagecomponent_list' , request=request),
        'Feature':reverse('feature_list',request=request) 
    })
class ImageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser)

class ImageDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
import psycopg2
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = '****secret_key****'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'imagedata',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'rest_framework',
    'storages',
]
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': [
        'rest_framework.views.exception_handler'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'imageserver1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'imageserver1.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'image_database',
       'USER': 'the_flash',
       'PASSWORD': 'password',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'


try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass

assert len(SECRET_KEY) > 20, 'Please set SECRET_KEY in local_settings.py'
```

**local_settings.py**

```
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'Get this from Amazon'
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'This as well'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'your-s3-bucket-name'
SECRET_KEY = '****secret_key****'
```

After doing all these I am stuck at the next step. All I want to do is upload the images from my local system to s3 through Django.I have been using [this](http://tech.marksblogg.com/file-uploads-amazon-s3-django.html) as reference.

Comment: No but now I don't know how to proceed further